# Elastic Search Complex Scenario

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I am quite new to Elastic Search. I have a complex scenario and I am unable to get the right solution(Elastic Queries/params) for this. Any Help would be highly appreciate.

My Fields

- Product Name (String)
- Price Min
- Price Max
- Availabilty Status(Avialable/Unavailable)

Beside of these a search will always be filter on unique user. So Mysql query looks like :

```
Select * from product where product_name like %xxx% AND price >= price_min AND price <= price_max AND availability = availability_ status AND user = 1;
```

I like the exact elastic search params to solve this scenario Or near about solution will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a filter here since you need an exact match and not a full-text match. And this way its even faster.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "filtered": { 
      "query": {
        "match": { "name": "YourName" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
           "must": [ 
           { "range": { "price_min": { "gte": 20 }}},
           { "range": { "price_max": { "lte": 170 }}},
           { "term" : { "availability" : "false" }} ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What you provide in "yourName" is a full text match (Similar names will be retrieved if the name field is analyzed). Im assuming that you have left it unchanged so the field is analyzed(Stemmed + stop words removal) by default.
Since you need the result to match all the criteria its an AND combination. Hence use

> bool filter to AND all the terms.

Answer (score 0):

So given your SQL query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM product
 WHERE product_name LIKE '%xxx%' 
   AND price >= price_min 
   AND price <= price_max 
   AND availability = availability_status 
   AND user = 1;
```

We need:

- a [`match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) for the `product_name`
- a [`range` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html) for the `price` field
- and a [`term` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html) for the `availability` and `user` fields

All these are wrapped inside a [`filtered` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) whose filters will filter out all non-matching documents, and finally the `match` query will run on the remaining documents to match the `product_name`

The correct query would then look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "product_name": "xxx"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "price": {
                  "gte": 20,
                  "lte": 170
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "availability": "availability_status"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "user": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please add your inputs here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60911130/elastic-search-coordinating-node-role-complex-aggregations