# Elastic search coordinating-node role - complex aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I understood coordinate node broadcasts the search request and gathers the results received from data nodes using  "query then fetch phase" .

Does it do it in one iteration of "query then fetch phase" or a search request can have multiple iterations of query then fetch phases?

Say taking a complex filter query taken from [Elastic Search Complex Scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257888/elastic-search-complex-scenario) (credits : Val, Thanks @Val), will it involve multiple iterations of query then fetch phases? what are the steps the coordinating node does to answer this query

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "product_name": "xxx"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "price": {
                  "gte": 20,
                  "lte": 170
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "availability": "availability_status"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "user": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got some hints. Posting it here for someone if they are curious

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-search-coordinating-node-role-complex-aggregations/225622/5

```
The details change as various things are optimised and evolve.
There are a number of "it depends" e.g. the "canMatch" pre-flight phase will not run if there's insufficient numbers of shards being queried or custom search routing is used or DFS is used.
Cross-cluster-search is another consideration.

Here's probably a good place to start if you're curious.
```